# How to add close mark to Auth0 Lock login screen in Android

Tags: android, auth0

I'm integrating Auth0 in my Android application and need to allow the user to skip/close the Auth0 login screen. However, I'm unable to show the close button.

For reference I added a screenshot showing the close button that I need to show in my application.
[image]

This is my code:

```
 Auth0 auth0 = new Auth0(
     getString(R.string.auth0_client_id), getString(R.string.auth0_domain));

 mLock = Lock.newBuilder(auth0, mCallback)
     //Add parameters to the builder
     .closable(true)// ITS NOT WORKING
     .build(this);

 broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
 broadcastManager.registerReceiver(receiver,
     new IntentFilter("com.auth0.android.lock.action.Authentication"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `closable(true)` option available in the Lock for Android does not trigger the appearance of a close button on the UI.

As per indicated in this [related GitHub issue](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-lock/issues/41), this is by design, and making it closable just lets the user go back in a standard Android way.